# Algorithm to extract polygones with holes

Tags: image-processing, algorithms, edge-detection

I have this picture and would like to extract the bones. 
First I thought of contour-Tracking, but as you can see in some bones there are holes (Like for example at the left finger, in the bone in the middle).

**What algorithm would you recommend me? To find the contour of the bones? How could I fill them?** Thanks

Im also grateful for code examples.
[image].

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply some image segmentation algorithms. You may read about A [Comparison of Image Segmentation Algorithms](http://riweb-backend.ri.cmu.edu/pub_files/pub4/pantofaru_caroline_2005_1/pantofaru_caroline_2005_1.pdf) and apply the ones that satisfies your needs better.

If you're developing with [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/), you can find some ready to use [(implemented) algorithms](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/d96/tutorial_py_table_of_contents_imgproc.html#gsc.tab=0) that can save you lot of work as it is the case with the [watershed algorithm](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html#gsc.tab=0).

Note that you can use OpenCV with the *traditional* programming language C/C++ but also many others such as [Python](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and [Java](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html). Personally I experienced it with C/C++ and Python though.